# VB.NET Outlook.items.itemadd event not firing. Trying to wait until an email is sent before executing code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, email, outlook, event-handling

### The problem

For the application I'm creating, the goal is to programmatically create an email (with the recipient, subject and body written), attach a file, send the email; then, finally, delete the file from the hard drive.

The problem I have is that I need the program to **wait for the email to finish sending** before it deletes the temporary attached file.

Sending the email isn't a problem, and I've read in my research into this problem that I should use the **Items.AddItem event on the Sent Mail folder.** This makes sense to me. Having the program delete the temp file when the AddItem event fires so it's waiting for the Sent Mail folder to have the mail item added to it sounds wonderful, but I can't get it to fire.

I used this MS Docs site as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd

I added the following references:

- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

Here's my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Scripting
Imports System.Environment

Public Class Form

    Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items
    Public olApp As Outlook.Application
    Public testfso As FileSystemObject
    Public testfilepath As String

    Public Sub Initialize_handler()
        olApp = New Outlook.Application 'initialise outlook app
        myOlItems = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items 'set sent folder variable for itemsadd event.
    End Sub

    Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd() Handles myOlItems.ItemAdd
        'This event should fire when the Sent Mail folder has an item added to it.
        MsgBox("Email sent.", vbOKOnly + vbApplicationModal + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Success")
        olApp.Quit() 'close outlook app.
        testfso.DeleteFile(testfilepath) 'delete temp test file.
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        testfilepath = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\temp.txt" 'File path for test temp file
        testfso = New FileSystemObject
        Dim file As TextStream = testfso.CreateTextFile(testfilepath, True) 'create test file.
        With file
            .Write("Some text here.")
            .Close()
        End With

        Call Initialize_handler() 'set the folder to "watch" with the itemsadd event.
        Dim eMail As Outlook.MailItem = olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) 'create email item.
        With eMail
            .Display() 'Show email (needs to be done now b/c the HTMLBody property is set to the email signature when the email is displayed with this method)
            .To = "recipient@gmail.com" 'set recipient.
            .Subject = "Test Email" 'set email subject.
            .HTMLBody = "Testing testing 123" & .HTMLBody 'add detail to start of email body.
            .Attachments.Add(testfilepath, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1) 'attach link file.
            .Send() 'Sent Folder ItemsAdd event should fire now.
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

### What happens

When I step through this code, it runs every line except when I get to the MailItem.send method, the AddItem event procedure doesn't fire and it simply continues to the end of the Form_Load sub.

### Other things I've tried

I tried `myOlItems = olApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items`
instead of `myOlItems = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items`
in the Initialize_handler sub, to no effect.

I also noticed that the MailItem unloads after it's sent so I tried a loop to have the program wait until the MailItem Is Nothing, but it simply hangs as if the MailItem doesn't actually become nothing.

**Can anyone help with this please?**

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `Items.ItemAdd` on the Sent Items folder will fire only after the message is actually sent, which might not happen for a long time.

You can also try to call `Namespace.SendAndReceive` after calling `Send`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this had no effect. You're right, it may take time for the email to send; and if it takes a while, the code would continue to step through line by line until the event is fired. I wonder if there's a more efficient way of waiting for the email to send

Comment: Since the MailItem.Send event is triggered by the send method, maybe we could use that somehow? Perhaps there's a way to wait until an event is triggered, perhaps with a loop?

Comment: `Send` event fires before the message is actually sent. `ItemAdd` is your first chance to see it after it was submitted. Does it work if Outlook is running at the time your code is executed and you click Send/Receive in Outlook?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, and I've experimented with this route because I tried using the MailItem.Sent property for this but I kept getting an exception saying the mail item has been moved or deleted. Also, I have, yes, and it's made no difference. I have been able to get the message boy to pop up saying "Message Sent" if I take my time while stepping through. It doesn't execute any o the following lines though, which would seem to indicate that it's a multi-thread processing problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calling `Send` doesn't guarantee that your mail item will be sent immediately. The method saves all of the message's properties and marks the message as ready to be sent. Outlook passes messages to the underlying messaging system in the order in which they are marked for sending. Because of this functionality, a message might stay in a message store for some time before the underlying messaging system can take responsibility for it. The order of receipt at the destination is in the underlying messaging system's control and does not necessarily match the order in which messages were sent.

The [SyncObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject) represents a `Send\Receive` group for a user and lets users configure different synchronization scenarios, selecting which folders and which filters apply. For example, the `Start` method begins synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group:

```
Public Sub Sync() 
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
 Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
 Dim i As Integer 
 Dim strPrompt As Integer 
 Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
 For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
strPrompt = MsgBox( _ 
 "Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
 syc.Start 
End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

There is an alternative method which Dmitry mentioned - the [NameSpace.SendAndReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.sendandreceive) method which initiates immediate delivery of all undelivered messages submitted in the current session, and immediate receipt of mail for all accounts in the current profile. So, to avoid synchronizing all accounts in Outlok which can take some time I'd suggest using the SyncObject's `Start` method described above.

Finally, be aware the message may not be put to the `Sent Items` folder at all, so you may not get the `ItemAdd` event fired all. The [MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) property returns or sets a `Folder` object that represents the folder in which a copy of the email message will be saved after being sent. So, it makes sense to check this value in the `ItemSend` event handler whether any add-in sets this on outgoing mails.

Another property which can play a vital role there is the [MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deleteaftersubmit) property which returns or sets a `Boolean` value that is `True` if a copy of the mail message is not saved upon being sent, and `False` if a copy is saved in `Sent Items` folder.

If you live in ideal and isolated world (without any add-ins) you may not care about these two properties, but if you need to deploy your solution widely it makes sense to pay attention to such facts as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out on this Eugene, all very good points. I'll integrate this into my code as (you're right) it'll definitely increase portability and reliability.